# Angular app doesn't include external libraries

Tags: angular, package.json

So I'm new to Angular and I've installed bootstrap with npm in node_modules of the project.
I dont know why, but every once in a while when I work on my project, the app "starts" this thing about not including bootstrap and other external libraries.
I'm working with Visual Studio Code, although I dont think it matters.
here's my angular.json :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Event": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Event",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [

            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Event:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Event:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Event:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Event-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Event:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Event:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Event"
}
```

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "eventim", 
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 6.1.2.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://AmitBL@bitbucket.org/AmitBL/event-planner.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/AmitBL/event-planner#readme"
}
```

If anyone has any idea what's causing it, I'll be grateful.
thank you.

Comment: Is it happening every time or randomly? How are you accessing bootstrap in your project? Just installing bootstrap package is not enough. You need to refer the bootstrap css file as well.

Comment: Yes it happens randomly, the project was okay about two hours ago and know it doesn't.
And where do I need to refer the bootstrap css file?

Comment: Include bootstrap css in angular.json in "styles" array OR import it in src/styles.css using `@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Comment: Well, the `@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` works, but I'm curious why angular.json is not including.
There are two "styles" arrays in angular.json.
I tried to add it to both of them and no luck.

Comment: In angular.json you have to provide node_modules path. try `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`. It just needs to be included in "styles" array of build config.

Comment: I did as you said, in both arrays, still, doesn't load bootstrap.css

Comment: Well, I don't see any reason that it should not work. Check the config in this Stackblitz [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqjaqr?file=angular.json)

Comment: Exactly the same, still doesn't work. I guess angular.json is somehow corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare bootstrap style in your **angular.json** in existing **styles** array

```
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  },
  "src/styles.css"
],
```

Comment: doesn't work, so frustrating.
Well I think the angular.json file is not binded to the project, I tried deleting styles.css from angular.json and it doesn't matter.
can I recreate angular.json file?